# Java PKI: SSL key/truststore persisted in a database?

Tags: java, ssl, pki

#### Scenario

To communicate with my server in a secure way, I generate a private key and a public key for the (well known) client, using the java keytool.

I deliver the new generated *client private key* and the *server public key* to the client.
I save the new generated *client public key* in the *server truststore*.

The *server private key* and *the server truststore* are so persisted in the file system where my server is running and loaded by starting up the server.

A new client (i.e. new private/public keys) could be added anytime, i.e. the server truststore must be updated.

I would like to focus my design on **scalability**.
Let's say I have 4 servers running simoultaneosly behind a loadbalancer, each with his own truststore.
If I add a new client, I have to update each single truststore.

#### Now the question:

It's a good idea to persist the server truststore (and maybe the server private key too) in a centralized Database (relational, nosql, whatever) without touching every single server node ?

Thank you for feedback!

Comment: That's a completely wrong approach. Create a CA certificate instead and use that to sign the client certificates/keys. Then put only the CA cert into the server truststore. Scales perfectly well. To generate/sign the client keys you can use something like XCA or KeyStore Explorer (keytool works too ofc).

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback.

Comment: My Problem is that the server should be able to communicate with the clients too.  Let's have two Client A and B and a server S. Client A send a message to S, encrypt it with the private key of A. Server S decrypt it with the public key of A and would like to redirect it to B. Server S encrypt the message with the private key of S and Client B decrypt it with the public key of S. For this kind of operations must I to save the public keys of each client (A,B)  in the truststore of the server (S), it's correct?

Comment: "Encrypting a message with the private key" is a signature (if you don't understand this, you should take your time and read a book about PKI first). A signature is usually packed into a PKCS#7 structure together with the certificate chain. The entity which is processing the signature then checks if it can validate the chain up to a trusted certificate. So still only a CA certificate required in the truststore.